# Can't log into tomcat manager

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

The only thing I did is to change the password of the admin user and I can't log in anymore !!!!!!  I got a 401 Unauthorized (?!?!)
/etc/tomcat7/tomcat-users.xml:

```
<tomcat-users>
<!--
  NOTE:  By default, no user is included in the "manager-gui" role required
  to operate the "/manager/html" web application.  If you wish to use this app,
  you must define such a user - the username and password are arbitrary.
-->
<!--
  NOTE:  The sample user and role entries below are wrapped in a comment
  and thus are ignored when reading this file. Do not forget to remove
  <!.. ..> that surrounds them.
-->
  <role rolename="tomcat"/>
  <role rolename="role1"/>
  <role rolename="admin" />
  <user username="admin" password="V3g$lb7p9pp" roles="standard,manager,admin,manager-gui"/>
  <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat"/>
  <user username="both" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat,role1"/>
  <user username="role1" password="tomcat" roles="role1"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define Roles before you can use them, add:

```
 <role rolename="standard"/>
 <role rolename="manager"/>
 <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
```

Also you need to restart the server, because this file is only read once at startup.